# Set Background Color Globally On On UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is the best to change globally all UIButtons background color?  I already set the tint globally

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate].window.tintColor =
```

Comment: Interesting...I did not know you could do that for the tint.  I usually use a "factory" like function to create buttons for Apps so that I can have them conform to a consistent style (background, shape, etc.).  It would be useful to know if you can set the background globally.

Comment: change globally all UIButtons text color ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"]
                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Or

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
```

Here's some more info on the appearance proxy: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: change globally all UIButtons text color

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
[[UIButton appearance] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```